# Moving through a stack in C

Tags: c, stack

I have a simple stack and I want to move through it using up and down functions. My `down` function seems to skip some numbers and it doesn't count correctly, if I move one place up then one place down the `down` function returns a value less than the value displayed by `up` function. Please help what am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 4096

typedef struct  s_stack
{
    int         capacity;
    int         count;
    int         top;
    char        *list[SIZE];
}               t_stack;

char    *up(t_stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->count == 0)
        return (stack->list[0]);
    return (stack->list[stack->count--]);
}

char    *down(t_stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->count > stack->top)
    {
        stack->count = stack->top;
        return ("");
    }
    if (stack->count < stack->top)
        return (stack->list[stack->count++]);
    return ("");
}

void        create_stack(t_stack *stack)
{
    memset(stack->list, 0, SIZE);
    stack->count = -1;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->capacity = SIZE;
}

void        push(t_stack *stack, char *value)
{
    if (stack->top == stack->capacity - 1)
        return ;
    stack->list[++stack->top] = value;
}

int main()
{
    t_stack         stack;
    create_stack(&stack);
    push(&stack, "1");  
    push(&stack, "2");  
    push(&stack, "3");  
    push(&stack, "4");  
    push(&stack, "5");  
    push(&stack, "6");  
    push(&stack, "7");  
    push(&stack, "8");  
    push(&stack, "9");  
    push(&stack, "10");
    stack.count = stack.top;
    while (1)
    {
        int ret;
        char buf[4];
        ret = read(0, buf, 4);
        if (buf[0] == 'u')
            printf("%s\n", up(&stack));
        else if (buf[0] == 'd')
            printf("%s\n", down(&stack));
        else
            break ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stacks are typically not for arbitrary traversal, but only support push and pop (and possibly peek). Sure you don't have a linear list? Don't get fancy with formatting. And `return` is a statement, not a function. Using parenthesis for its expression can result in subtle errors.

Comment: `top` is keeping track of the last item, and `count` is for iterating.

Comment: If you want to move `up` and `down`, you can use a doubly linked list, instead of a stack. Or even a simple array structure would be good for this.

Comment: Look what happens in your `up()` if `stack->count` is `-1` (the initial value).

Comment: You don't want a stack. Don't use well-established names in wrong context. This only leads to confusion.

Comment: @RoadRunner: There is a reason to differentiate between a data structure and its operators and the implementation. Stacks are abstrations and often linked lists are used to implement stacks.

Comment: Yes @Olaf, Just offering suggestions to the OP. I know that linked lists are used to implement stacks and queues, just offering a more suitable data structure for the OP to use. No harm in that.

Answer (score 0):

> My `down` function seems to skip some numbers and it doesn't count correctly

In `down()`, you at least have to remove

```
    if (stack->count < stack->top)
```

since `stack->list[stack->top]` is the valid last item in your `stack`.

> if I move one place up then one place down the `down` function returns a value less than the value displayed by `up` function.

What may be confusing is that `up()` as well as `down()` display the value they are moving away from, so when `up()` moves from `10` to `9` it shows `10`, and when the following `down()` moves from `9` back to `10` it shows `9`.